# $wpdb not working, doesn't show anything in posts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I was looking for using wpdb to fetch data from database and also display on a post in Wordpress. Unfortunately, I could not to do that and wpdb not working for me.
this is my code :

```
<?php
    $results= $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT Product_Name from print_drug");
    foreach ($results as $obj){
      echo $obj->Product_Name;
    }
?>
```

but after save then preview, i can see nothing on a page to show and i think wpdb->get_results return a null array. :)

and also i used this following code to see my returned array is empty or not:

```
if (!empty($results) {
echo "1";
} else {
echo "2";
}
```

but i didn't see anything on a page and no output was there.

what should i do ?

Comment: use `var_dump($results);` to inspect the results

Comment: use ```var_dump($results);``` to see what does **$results** return.

Comment: Have you loaded the $wpdb variable like this `global $wpdb;` before making the database call and is your table and column name correct. Seeing that you say even on empty check nothing was printed, my bet is that your code broke before performing the check and hence blank page.

Comment: didn't Work :(
`[insert_php]

global $wpdb;
$results= $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT Product_Name from print_drug");
var_dump($results);
[/insert_php]`
and use the [insert_php] instead of <?php> because of the plugin.
what plugin do you use ?

Comment: First, try `global $wpdb;` and change your query to say `SELECT * FROM print_drug` to see if it actually displays anything. If not, try something like `SELECT * FROM wp_options`.

Comment: nothing to show :( and not working.

Answer (score 2):

I see you are using a plugin for inserting snippets of PHP code into the posts/pages' contents. If you want to know what is happening with your query, insert the following piece of code into the page's content:

```
[insert_php]
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->show_errors();
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Product_Name from print_drug");
$wpdb->print_error();
$wpdb->hide_errors();
[/insert_php]
```

If your WordPress is a multisite installation, use the piece of code:

```
[insert_php]
if(!defined('DIEONDBERROR')) define( 'DIEONDBERROR', true );
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->show_errors();
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Product_Name from print_drug");
$wpdb->print_error();
$wpdb->hide_errors();
[/insert_php]
```

Comment: Could you indicate the code you are entering exactly and where, furthermore of the plugin's you are using for inserting the snippet of PHP code in posts and pages?

Comment: I use (Insert PHP) plugin and use this code: `[insert_php]
define( 'DIEONDBERROR', true );
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->show_errors();
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Product_Name from print_drug");
$wpdb->print_error();
$wpdb->hide_errors();
[/insert_php]` but i returned nothing on the page to show.

Comment: There are multiple plugins for inserting php code in pages and posts, I will assume you are using the "PHP code snippets (Insert PHP)", in the code please, remove define( 'DIEONDBERROR', true );  look the screenshots visiting the links https://wordpress.dwbooster.com/customdownloads/2018/07/23/screenshot_code.png and https://wordpress.dwbooster.com/customdownloads/2018/07/23/screenshot_public_webpage.png

Comment: it's done and finally worked :), thanks for your help. but do you know how to put them in a table ?

Comment: So, I guess my code has helped you to detect the issue and fix it. Share your current code and what do you want to implement.

Comment: Well. now i have a image URL saved in my database, is there anyway to this image on the page Mike ? thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is too general, and the solution depends of many conditions. I recommend you create a new ticket with your code.

Comment: This is my new topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51511420/show-picture-in-wordpress-with-php-code i hope you can help me ;)

Comment: Hi, if my answer has helped you to implement your project, I would appreciate a positive vote.